# React: Context to pass state between two hierarchies of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-context

I am developing a website in which I want to be able to access the state information anywhere in the app. I have tried several ways of implementing state but I always get following error message:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SOS`.

Here is my SOS->index.js file:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CONST from '../utils/Constants';
import { Grid, Box, Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { Header } from '../Layout';
import ListItem from './ListItem';
import SOSButton from './SOSButton';
import FormPersonType from './FormPersonType';
import FormEmergencyType from './FormEmergencyType';
import StateContext from '../App';
import Context from '../Context';

export default function SOS() {
  const { componentType, setComponentType } = useContext(Context);
  const timerOn = false;
  //'type_of_person',
  const ambulance = false;
  const fire_service = false;
  const police = false;
  const car_service = false;

  //static contextType = StateContext;
  const showSettings = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleComponentType = e => {
    console.log(e);
    //this.setState({ componentType: 'type_of_emergency' });
    setComponentType('type_of_emergency');
  };

  const handleEmergencyType = new_emergency_state => {
    console.log(new_emergency_state);
    //   this.setState(new_emergency_state);
  };

  const onSubmit = e => {
    console.log('in OnSubmit');
    axios
      .post(CONST.URL + 'emergency/create', {
        id: 1,
        data: this.state //TODO
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  let component;

  if (componentType == 'type_of_person') {
    component = (
      <FormPersonType handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType} />
    );
  } else if (componentType == 'type_of_emergency') {
    component = (
      <FormEmergencyType
        handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
        handleEmergencyType={this.handleEmergencyType}
        emergencyTypes={this.state}
        timerStart={this.timerStart}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header title="Send out SOS" />
      <StateContext.Provider value="type_of_person" />
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
        {component}
      </Container>
      {/*component = (
        <HorizontalNonLinearStepWithError
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
        />*/}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Just for reference, the Context file is defined as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Context = React.createContext();

const ContextProvider = props => {
  const [componentType, setComponentType] = useState('');
  setComponentType = 'type_of_person';
  //const [storedNumber, setStoredNumber] = useState('');
  //const [functionType, setFunctionType] = useState('');
  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        componentType,
        setComponentType
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextProvider;
```

EDIT: I have changed my code according to your suggestions (updated above). But now I get following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentType' of undefined

Comment: You can't change the value of `affected` by this way. You need to use the function returned by the second position by `useState`: `const [affected, setAffected] = useState(''); setAffected('type_of_person');`

Comment: What do you mean *"if I uncomment the render function"*? You're writing a functional component, not a class-based one; it doesn't have a `render` method.

Comment: You need to read up on functional and class components! https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components

Comment: Also, `useContext(Context)` will return an object, so you can't do this `if`: `componentType == 'type_of_person'`. You could access it using `const { affected: componentType } = useContext(Context)`

Comment: @Macabeus thank you, could you help me with the new error which you can see in the edit of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Context` is not the default export from your `../Context` file so you have to import it as:

`import { Context } from '../Context';`

Otherwise, it's trying to import your `Context.Provider` component.

For your file structure/naming, the proper usage is:

```js
// Main app file (for example)
// Wraps your application in the context provider so you can access it anywhere in MyApp
import ContextProvider from '../Context'

export default () => {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <MyApp />
    </ContextProvider>
  )
}
```

```js
// File where you want to use the context
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Context } from '../Context'

export default () => {
  const myCtx = useContext(Context)

  return (
    <div>
      Got this value - { myCtx.someValue } - from context
    </div>
  )
}
```

And for godsakes...rename your Context file, provider, and everything in there to something more explicit. I got confused even writing this.

Comment: Thank you! And how can I modify the context attributes in other files apart from the main app file?

Comment: Call your setComponentType function that is passed down through your context. Your context (the way you set it up) is an object. So when you call `const myCtx=useContext(Context)`, you'll have access to `myCtx.componentType` and `myCtx.setComponentType()`. If it's broken right now, it's because you have `setComponentType = 'type_of_person';` in your Context file. Remove that and set your initial context with `const [componentType, setComponentType] = useState('type_of_person')`